# Open VMware Tool reporting VMSVC Too many partitions

Tags: vmware-server

I have a virtual machine running with the warning below.

```
vmsvc[895]: [ warning] [guestinfo] Too many partitions
vmsvc[895]: [ warning] [guestinfo] Failed to update VMDB
```

I believe this could be linked to the great number of quota mounts that are listed in the fstab but unsure.

Very little found on this error when searching the internet.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many positions are mounted on the server?

Comment: These aren't exactly disk volumes, these are entries in fstab which relate to the quotas package to restrict how much data users can store. But there must be around 800.